# Hide video url on video player

Tags: android, vlc, android-video-player

I am getting video from my server (myserver.com/salsa/myVideo.mp4) and playing it on default android application using

```
Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(myServer.com/salsa/myVideo.mp4), "video/*");
startActivity(tostart);
```

In my own phone, I am using MXPlayer application to play videos. Today I downloaded the VLC player android application to see how it looks. When I select VLC to play video, on top of it, the video url is shown to the user. However I don't want users to see the url.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to hide url?

**Edit:** In MXPlayer instead of showing domain name or folder name, it shows myVideo.mp4 So a user can easily combine this 2 information, and can get the URL

Comment: If you want to control the video in your application use **<VideoView>** insted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to hide url?

Write your own video player.

Otherwise, the decision of whether or not to show the URL is up to the developer of the other application, not you.